# How to determine what happens behind the scene in .Net

Tags: .net-3.5, compiler-construction

What tool or method can I use to see what code something like an anonymous method or LINQ statement gets compiled to?  Basicly seeing what happens behind the scene?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Reflector](http://www.red-gate.com/products/reflector/) is an excellent way to do this.

Go to View / Options / Optimization and choose "None" so that it won't try to work out what the C# originally was.

For example, the `Main` method of this little app:

```
using System;

class Test    
{
    static void Main()
    {
        string other = "hello";
        Foo (x => new { Before = other + x, After = x + other });
    }

    static void Foo<T>(Func<int, T> func) {}
}
```

is decompiled to:

```
private static void Main()
{
    <>c__DisplayClass1 class2;
    class2 = new <>c__DisplayClass1();
    class2.other = "hello";
    Foo(new Func<int, <>f__AnonymousType0<string, string>>(class2.<Main>b__0));
    return;
}
```

and then you look in `<>c__DisplayClass1` and `<>f_AnonymousType0` for more details etc.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [ildasm](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f7dy01k1%28VS.80%29.aspx) to view the MSIL output of the compiler.

Answer (score 1):

There is one another way if you wanted to get inside and whats going on in .Net framework when we call the CLR methods.

If you are using VS 2008, you can even debug the .net framework source code. For this you need to install [**Microsoft source reference server hotfixes**](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/Downloads/DownloadDetails.aspx?DownloadID=10443&wa=wsignin1.0)..

And [**Shawn Burke**](http://blogs.msdn.com/sburke/archive/2008/01/16/configuring-visual-studio-to-debug-net-framework-source-code.aspx) got an excellent post (step by step guide)  to configure this thing..

Just give a try..